# C# - Call base and class constructors in derived class

Tags: c#, inheritance, constructor

Suppose I have the following base and derived class in my C# program:

```
class BaseClass
{
    public BaseClass() { }
    public BaseClass(int someVal) 
    { 
        // do something here 
    }
}

class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public DerivedClass(string somethingNew) 
        : base()
    {
        // do something with the somethingNew varible
    }
    public DerivedClass(string somethingNew, int someVal)
        : base(someVal)
    {
        // do **THE SAME THING** with the somethingNew varible as in first constructor
    }
}
```

My question comes about in the final constructor - Ideally, what I'd like is to be able to do something along the lines of (although this won't compile):

```
    public DerivedClass(string somethingNew, int someVal)
        : base(someVal)
        : this(somethingNew)
    {

    }
```

In other words, call both the `base` and the first constructor.

Is there any way to do this or do I just need to re-write the code inside each constructor in this case?

Thanks!!

Comment: Your `(string somethingNew)` ctor in `DerivedClass` calls` base()` - in your proposed example, would you expect the explicit `base(someVal)` to override the `base()` call in `this(somethingNew)`?

Comment: @NWard, good question - In my (very specific) case, it wouldn't make a difference since the 2 methods don't contradict, but I can see how that could cause issues. In my case, I would basically **want** it to call the `base(someVal)` and then the code from within the `this(somethingNew)` constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not to say this is the CORRECT answer (and I'd love to hear how others would recommend I do this), but what I ended up doing was creating a private setter method that either constructor can call along the following lines:

```
class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public DerivedClass(string somethingNew) 
        : base()
    {
        setVals(somethingNew);
    }
    public DerivedClass(string somethingNew, int someVal)
        : base(someVal)
    {
        setVals(somethingNew);
    }

    private setVals(string somethingNew) 
    {
        // do something with the somethingNew varible
    }
}
```

It saved my issue of having to deal with repetitive code and seems to be the cleanest way to do this, but, as I said, I'd love to see what others recommend / if there's a way to do this better.

Thanks!!!

Comment: This is exactly what I would have answered. Naming wise, I've seen `Init` used a lot, which may be good if the initialisation turns out to need more than just setting values.

Answer (score 1):

You could accomplish this using default, nullable parameters values in your constructors.

```
class BaseClass
{
    public BaseClass(int? someVal = null) 
    { 
        if (someVal.HasValue) 
        {
            //Do something here
        }
    }
}

class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public DerivedClass(string somethingNew, int? someVal = null) 
        : base(someVal) // Pass someVal into BaseClass
    {
         // Do something with SomethingNew
    }
}
```

Which can then be called as:

`var d = new DerivedClass("SomeValue");`

`var d2 = new DerivedClass("SomeOtherValue", 2);`

Answer (score 1):

I would design base class like this

```
class BaseClass
{
    public BaseClass() { ... }
    public BaseClass(int someVal) : this() { }
}
```

to ensure what `...` code is executed always.